# Dynamic programming: Task planification variation

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, job-scheduling

I'm struggling with a dynamic programming problem for a couple of days. It goes like this:
John's working day is divided in N time slots, every slot i having associated a gain G[i] which he can receive is he works in that time slot. If he decides to work in the time interval [i, j] his total reward would be R[i,j]=G[i+1]+...+G[j] as the first slot is for warming up. Everyday he has to work exactly T slots - he can chose a subset of T slots from the available N total slots. He wants to maximize his profit by choosing a set of disjunct intervals [a1,b1], [a2,b2], ...[ak,bk] with 1 <= a1 <= b1 < a2 <= b2 <...< ak <= bk and Sum[i=1, k](bi-ai+1)=T.

Example: N=7, T=5 and the gain vector {3,9,1,1,7,5,4}. The optimal solution is selecting the intervals [1,2] and [4,6] with a total profit of 9+12=21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DP solution:
int f[i][j][0..1];

```
let f[i][j][0] denotes the maximal gain for the first i time slots and using j time slots, and the i-th time slot is not used.
let f[i][j][1] denotes the maximal gain for the first i time slots and using j time slots, and the i-th time slot is used.

obviously,f[i][j][k] can determine f[i+1][j][k] or f[i+1][j+1][k]. details below:
f[i+1][j+1][1]=max(f[i+1][j+1][1],f[i][j][0],f[i][j][1]+G[i+1]);
f[i+1][j][0]=max(f[i+1][j][0],f[i][j][0],f[i][j][1]);
```